Problem with unziping non latin language(Russian)
Im using Ubuntu system and python, and i created a script that downloads zip files from a site. The zip files are in russian and when the program unzips them they come out as something like this "ÅÑτáΓ¡á∩ Σ«α¼á Readme.txt.pdf". Strange thing is its the same when i unzip it manually(on Ubuntu), on Windows if i unzip these manually there is no program but if the script does it same happens. When i force the program to use UTF-8 it creates shapes with '?' inside of them, i even tries the command "convmv -f windows-1251 -t utf8 --notest -r ./extracted_directory" but it just changed it to "ЏҐз в­ п д®а¬  “Џ„ ьЊ’“#407000114 ®в 31.07.24.pdf" and the PC considers it "already in UTF-8". Also, im downloading the files from the site that zips automatically if there is more than 1 file, if i just download 1 everything is fine and the file retains its name in russian as its suppose to. Did anyone ever encounter something of this sort and or knows how to deal with it? thanks in advance :)
Tried unzipping with a lot of different zipping tools.

7z allows to pass with encoding. According to documenation, the encoding you looking for is cp866
Standard Encodings
7z x -mcp=CP866 yourfile.zip


Almost worked, I later asked ChatGPT and it gave me a similar command: unzip -O CP866 yourfile.zip and it worked, thanks alot!!
